# how can I drag text from one a textbox to another textbox in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, drag, drop

I have 20 textboxes in a userform and I want to move the text from textbox1 to
textbox5 by dragging and dropping it with the mouse, but I really have no idea how to do this. I am not an experienced programmer in VBA so maybe it is not even possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VBA required! It is simple than you think :)

Set the `DragBehavior` of the TextBox to `fmDragBehaviorEnabled` at design time as shown below and you are done

[image]

**In Action**

[image]